# Analytically solve $\Phi(\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma}) = c$ for $\mu$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $\Phi(\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma}) = c$, for known parameters $\sigma$, $c$ and $d$, but unknown $\mu$, is there a way to analytically solve for $\mu$? I know that the CDF is strictly decreasing in $\mu$, so finding $\mu$ numerically is easy, but I am looking for an analytical way.

Comment: $\mu = d - \sigma \Phi^{-1}(c)$.

Comment: Thank you - I'd gladly accept it as the real answer as well - if you post it as one.

Comment: I did that, but got downvoted and my answer marked for deletion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu = d - \sigma \Phi^{-1}(c)$..

Comment: This is exactly what I had asked for. I do not understand why this answer deserved a downvote. I somehow did not see the forset for the trees and zhoraster's answer was exactely what I needed.